# Perl syntax is not highlighted

Tags: eclipse, perl, debugging, eclipse-plugin, epic

I have **Eclipse SDK Version: 3.5.2** with **EPIC 0.5.46** installed on **Ubuntu Linux**. I was writing some Perl code which I could run/debug correctly. The syntax was always highlighted. recently I had to add one *.pl file to my project and debug it. However, for some reason, the code is not being highlighted. What might be the reason for this behavior? My guess was that maybe there is some issue with Eclipse/EPIC adding/importing new files to the existing project but I'm not sure. Please consider even basic mistakes with Eclipse/EPIC configuration and projects management since I'm new to it. Thanks!

Comment: Are you opening it *in* the Perl Perspective?

Comment: @Axeman Yeah sure. Otherwise it wouldn't debug/run Perl code.

Comment: Does it definitely still have the *.pl extension? EPIC doesn't seem to be able to do syntax highlighting without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that I found the problem which was preventing my Perl code from being highlighted. I've noticed that in the first lines of my `.pl` file, there is a **commented** line which include a weird `?` symbol as appears on the screenshot below:

[image]

The moment I removed this symbol, all the code became highlighted! So it seems that there was some issue with text encoding which prevented Eclipse ho highlight the coded correctly.

Comment: The file is Latin1 encoded, you opened it as UTF-8. Tell the editor the correct encoding since its auto-detection failed or is not existent.

Comment: @daxim Thanks for your comment! However, as I can see, there is only limited list of "Other" text encoding options in Eclipse and none of them shows the character correctly. Any idea if it's possible to add an encoding to Eclipse?

Comment: No idea. Contact the EPIC/Eclipse devs.

Answer (score 5):

You should right-click the file and then open with "epic perl editor", then everything will be fine!